# How can i authenticate a user without using Drupal functions?

Tags: 7, users

I need to authenticate a D7 user from a php page from outside a Drupal session. In D6 i could have used the md5() function, now i've seen that this is not possible due to changes to D7 authentication. How can i do it without using Drupal functions?

Comment: what parameters would you use to authenticate the user? username and password?

Comment: yes, only username and passwd; i do not need anything other

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use any Drupal function?

Comment: I am building a webservice that needs to use some tables in my Drupal database (from which the user table); the WS will be invoked a lot of times so i don't want it to load the Drupal stuff every time, if possible.

Comment: You could also build the web service with Drupal, since it is accessing Drupal data, and only Drupal can authenticate its users.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the `includes/password.inc` file in your drupal 7 installation, you can see how drupal 7 hashes up the password and then code that up separately or just include that file in your other script.  A quick tutorial on this can also be found [here](http://www.coderintherye.com/generate-password-user-drupal-7).

Comment: That would mean to still use Drupal functions. To make it clear to the OP, or future readers, the problem is not using a Drupal function, but including the right file.

Comment: as I said, 'code that up separately' OR just include the file--the file mentioned includes the logic of how drupal 7 hashes the password.

Comment: If you include includes/password.inc, you are still using Drupal functions, and copying the code from includes/password.inc to another file doesn't make sense, if includes/password.inc is available. The comment was a note for the OP, to say the solution is not avoiding using a Drupal function, but including the right file.